# Laravel return null for existing value in model

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

after getting query from database in `Controller` i have this output:

```
$newTickets = Ticket::with('user')->whereStatus(0)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get();

dd($newTickets[0]->user);
```

output:

```
#attributes: array:18 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "active" => 1
    "name" => "user1"
    "family" => "user1111"
    "username" => "xxxxx"
    "avatar" => "user_bg3.jpg"
    "email" => "p@p.com"
    "email_verified_at" => null
    "user_id" => null
    "properties_id" => null
    "password" => "$2y$10$b50fMYQMfMyJgtgCDEfQyueu.C.VfhfQCXT/f2Y8ObAe4nMrNiXEe"
    "mobile_number" => "333333"
    "device_id" => "0123456789"
    "api_token" => "aaaaaaa"
    "remember_token" => null
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2020-06-02 13:13:15"
    "updated_at" => "2020-06-02 13:13:15"
]
```

now when i try to show `avatar` field value, i'm getting `null` :|

```
dd($newTickets[0]->user->avatar);
```

output:

```
null
```

whats problem and why i can't get this value and that return null?

i can get another values and my problem is only getting `avatar` value

`User` model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, SoftDeletes;

    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'avatar' => 'array',
    ];

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserGroup::class, 'user_user_group');
    }

    public function child()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class)->with('child');
    }

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function blogs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserBlog::class);
    }

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
    }

    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->name.' '.$this->family;
    }
}
```

Comment: you sure you don't have get attribute for avatar? or any cast?

Comment: Do you have any relation, accessor or mutator with the name of avatar in your user model?

Comment: @MiladTeimouri yes i'm sure. my post updated

Comment: @OMR you are right, problem solved

Comment: Why you cast avatar to array in line 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are casting avatar to an array ...
when you do this ... laravel automatically decode 'avatar' from json for output and encode it for input ...
[more details](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

just remove avatar from :

```
  protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'avatar' => 'array',
    ];
```